# Does Stackdriver provide a c++ client library?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries

The above link provides the references for client libraries. It doesnt seem to have a c++ library, Is this conclusion right?

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no official support for C++. What you can do however, is to create a feature request to the Stackdriver team using the Google [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187203&template=1162688) for them to evaluate the possibility to add support for this language.